# JSF, How to get Id of <h:input> from Managed Bean

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, richfaces

I have this code in my XHTML page :

```
<p:cellEditor>
    <f:facet name="output">
        <h:outputText value="#{complaint.description}" />
    </f:facet>
    <f:facet name="input">
        <p:inputText id="thisInput" value="#{complaint.description}" style="width:96%"/>
    </f:facet>
</p:cellEditor>
```

how can i get the value of id "this Input" in the managed Bean ?

Comment: Why do you want to get id???

Comment: I have two inpout (IP1 and IP2).
When I was entering a value I want to know what inpout I took the value that is in IP1 or IP2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind the component to the managed bean, by using the `binding` attribute (assuming that `component` is the managed bean you want to have the component bound):

```
<p:inputText id="thisInput" 
             value="#{complaint.description}" 
             style="width:96%"
             binding="#{complaint.inputText}" />
```

In the managed bean, you have to have a member and accessor methods for it (getter and setter):

```
private InputText inputText;

//+ accessors
```

Finally, in order to get the component's `id` in the managed bean, you can invoke the [`UIComponent#getClientId()`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html#getClientId()) method. For example:

```
String id = inputText.getClientId();
```

---

Side note: Binding components to the managed bean in considered as a practice and should be avoided, unless there's no very specific reason that requires component binding.